# How to pass the charset and the Firebird's role using R

Tags: r, database, connection, firebird, jaybird

I'm trying to execute a select in Firebird using the R language. I know that Firebird needs a charset and role parameter, but I don't know how to pass this in R language.
Default message without inform the charset

```
   WARNING: No connection character set specified (property lc_ctype, encoding, charSet or localEncoding), defaulting to character set NONE
```

Comment: ROLE parameter is optional, you are not mandated to create SQL roles and use them, if you don't want

Comment: what connection library you use Java JDBC ?  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RJDBC/index.html   Show the R code you use to open the database connection, including the connection string

Comment: @Arioch'The Given the error message, he is using Jaybird (Firebird JDBC driver).

Comment: Please show how you connect.

Comment: BTW: This message is a **warning**, Firebird doesn't _need_ a character set, but it is better if you specify it (to avoid transliteration problems, invalid characters, etc).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I had such an impression, but I hope the TS to put this explicitly. Too many DB connection libraries of different backgrounds in R

Comment: when using c3p0 and you do not want to see warnings like that, you can set  <Logger name="com.mchange" level="warn"/>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message indicates you are using Jaybird (the Firebird JDBC driver). Given you haven't shown any information on how you connect, I'll answer from a generic usage perspective.

There are multiple ways to pass properties to Jaybird on connect, but the simplest (assuming you are using a JDBC URL), is to include those properties in the URL.

So if your URL is

```
jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost/employee
```

Then you can add properties by adding a `?` and adding (&-separated) `key=value` pairs:

```
jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost/employee?charSet=utf-8&roleName=yourRole
```

For specifying the character set you can use either the property `charSet` with a Java character set or `encoding` with a Firebird character set. See also the [Jaybird FAQ on character sets](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/faq.html#character-sets).

For specifying a role, you can use `roleName`.

See also the [Jaybird JDBC Driver Java Programmer’s Manual](https://firebirdsql.github.io/jaybird-manual/jaybird_manual.html#_appendices) and the list of [connection properties on the wiki](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/jaybird/wiki/Connection-properties).